# How can I force Spark to execute code?

Tags: java, scala, hadoop, apache-spark

How can I force Spark to execute a call to map, even if it thinks it does not need to be executed due to its lazy evaluation?

I have tried to put `cache()` with the map call but that still doesn't do the trick. My map method actually uploads results to HDFS. So, its not useless, but Spark thinks it is.

Comment: This question suffers the same problem as [your previous one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31383733/1093528): no code to work with. Please post example code. Also, if this is related to the same problem, do not open a new question.

Comment: That is a general question. Basically, how to stop Spark from making assumptions and execute whatever code I give to it.

Comment: We can't tell what assumptions Spark is making without the code that you claim it's making assumptions about. Post the code, please.

Comment: Just out of interest, why would you want this? Spark is Spark with a definite thing in mind.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

**Short answer:**

To force Spark to execute a transformation, you'll need to require a result. Sometimes a simple `count` action is sufficient.

**TL;DR:**

Ok, let's review the **`RDD` operations**.

`RDD`s support two types of operations:

- **transformations** - which create a new dataset from an existing one.
- **actions** -  which return a value to the driver program after running a computation on the dataset.

For example, `map` is a transformation that passes each dataset element through a function and returns a new RDD representing the results. On the other hand, `reduce` is an action that aggregates all the elements of the RDD using some function and returns the final result to the driver program (although there is also a parallel `reduceByKey` that returns a distributed dataset).

All transformations in Spark are **lazy**, in that *they do not compute their results right away*.

Instead, they just remember the transformations applied to some base dataset (e.g. a file). ***The transformations are only computed when an action requires a result*** to be returned to the driver program. This design enables Spark to run more efficiently – for example, we can realize that a dataset created through map will be used in a reduce and return only the result of the reduce to the driver, rather than the larger mapped dataset.

By default, each transformed `RDD` may be recomputed each time you run an action on it. However, you may also persist an `RDD` in memory using the `persist` (or `cache`) method, in which case Spark will keep the elements around on the cluster for much faster access the next time you query it. There is also support for persisting `RDD`s on disk, or replicated across multiple nodes.

### Conclusion

To force Spark to execute a call to map, you'll need to require a result. Sometimes a `count` action is sufficient.

### Reference

- [Spark Programming Guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html).

Comment: What is the difference between persist and cache? And aren't RDDs persisted in memory anyway if they are only used once?

Comment: With `cache`, you use only the default storage level MEMORY_ONLY. With `persist`, you can specify which storage level you want. Use `persist` if you want to assign another storage level than MEMORY_ONLY to the RDD

Comment: How about using "take" to trigger persist ?
I did an experiment with version 1.6.1, "count" would need one more stage (comprised of shuffle and aggregate)than "take".
So I think it is more efficient by using "take" action.

Comment: Is there a list of all actions somewhere?

Comment: @rsmith54 https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.1/programming-guide.html#actions gives the most common ones, and there should be a link to the docs for an exhaustive list for whichever language you use

Comment: That is useful for the most common, but it would be great to have an exhaustive list of actions.

Comment: @eliasah what do you mean by sometimes? i would like to know more about the conditions when a count action wouldn't trigger intermediate map steps.

Answer (score 16):

Spark [transformations](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#transformations) only describe what has to be done. To trigger an execution you need an [action](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#actions).

In your case there is a deeper problem. If goal is to create some kind of side effect, like storing data on HDFS, the right method to use is `foreach`. It is both an action and has a clean semantics. What is also important, unlike `map`, it doesn't imply referential transparency.

Comment: Would foreach also execute in parallel? Can you give some example?

Comment: Yes, it is executed in parallel on the worker nodes. The simplest thing is to log or print things. Using PySpark: `from __future__ import print_function;
rdd.foreach(print)`. Another option is to `foreachPartition`.