# How to force DataFrame evaluation in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Sometimes (e.g. for testing and bechmarking) I want force the execution of the transformations defined on a DataFrame. AFAIK calling an action like `count` does not ensure that all `Columns` are actually computed, `show` may only compute a subset of all `Rows` (see examples below)

My solution is to write the `DataFrame` to HDFS using `df.write.saveAsTable`, but this "clutters" my system with tables I don't want to keep any further.

So what is the best way to trigger the evaluation of a `DataFrame`?

Edit:

Note that there is also a recent discussion on the spark developer list : http://apache-spark-developers-list.1001551.n3.nabble.com/Will-count-always-trigger-an-evaluation-of-each-row-td21018.html

I made a small example which shows that `count` on `DataFrame` does not evaluate everything (tested using Spark 1.6.3 and spark-master = `local[2]`):

```
val df = sc.parallelize(Seq(1)).toDF("id")
val myUDF = udf((i:Int) => {throw new RuntimeException;i})

df.withColumn("test",myUDF($"id")).count // runs fine
df.withColumn("test",myUDF($"id")).show() // gives Exception
```

Using the same logic, here an example that `show` does not evaluate all rows:

```
val df = sc.parallelize(1 to 10).toDF("id")
val myUDF = udf((i:Int) => {if(i==10) throw new RuntimeException;i})

df.withColumn("test",myUDF($"id")).show(5) // runs fine
df.withColumn("test",myUDF($"id")).show(10) // gives Exception
```

Edit 2 : For Eliasah: The Exception says this:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 6.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 6.0 (TID 6, localhost): java.lang.RuntimeException
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$anonfun$1.apply$mcII$sp(<console>:68)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$anonfun$1.apply(<console>:68)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$anonfun$1.apply(<console>:68)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificUnsafeProjection.apply(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.Project$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(basicOperators.scala:51)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.Project$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(basicOperators.scala:49)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
.
.
.
.

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1431)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1419)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1418)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1418)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1640)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1599)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1588)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:620)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1832)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1845)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1858)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:212)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.Limit.executeCollect(basicOperators.scala:165)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeCollectPublic(SparkPlan.scala:174)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$DataFrame$$execute$1$1.apply(DataFrame.scala:1500)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$DataFrame$$execute$1$1.apply(DataFrame.scala:1500)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.withNewExecutionId(DataFrame.scala:2087)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.org$apache$spark$sql$DataFrame$$execute$1(DataFrame.scala:1499)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.org$apache$spark$sql$DataFrame$$collect(DataFrame.scala:1506)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$$anonfun$head$1.apply(DataFrame.scala:1376)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$$anonfun$head$1.apply(DataFrame.scala:1375)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.withCallback(DataFrame.scala:2100)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.head(DataFrame.scala:1375)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.take(DataFrame.scala:1457)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.showString(DataFrame.scala:170)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.show(DataFrame.scala:350)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.show(DataFrame.scala:311)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.show(DataFrame.scala:319)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:74)
.
.
.
.
```

Comment: My answer here will help you as your assumption is wrong http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31383904/how-can-i-force-spark-to-execute-code/31384084#31384084

Comment: Secondly I'm not sure that I understand your problem : "this "clutters" my system with tables I don't want to keep any further." What does that mean ?

Comment: Do you need unit testing on DataFrame transformations ?

Comment: @eliasah I would prefer calling an action on my dataframe which has no side-effects, writing hive-tables is a (unwanted) side-effect, thats what I meant with cluttering.

Comment: But count doesn't have side effect. Your assumption is wrong Raphael. count insures that all columns are computed.

Comment: @eliasah Can you elaborate which of my assumption is wrong, the answer you linked does not really relate to my question, I'm well aware of the difference between transformations and actions.

Comment: @eliasah according to this discussion (http://apache-spark-developers-list.1001551.n3.nabble.com/Will-count-always-trigger-an-evaluation-of-each-row-td21018.html, see post of Matei Zaharia), `count` on dataframe seems not to evaluate all columns. But I'm happy if this is not true

Comment: Ok I withdraw then my claim. I'm sorry about that. Let me look back to it. The definition given by Matei is kind a misleading I believe with all due respect for him

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't believe that what he says is correct neither.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137738/discussion-between-eliasah-and-raphael-roth).

Comment: The discussion link that you have given is very interesting.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I guess simply getting an underlying `rdd` from `DataFrame` and triggering an action on it should achieve what you're looking for.

```
df.withColumn("test",myUDF($"id")).rdd.count // this gives proper exceptions
```

Comment: This is weird. Looks like this answer worked for the original question but someone still managed to give couple of downvotes without mentioning any reason or feedback. :)

Answer (score 24):

It's a bit late, but here's the fundamental reason: `count` does not act the same on `RDD` and `DataFrame`.

In `DataFrame`s there's an optimization, as in some cases you do not require to load data to actually know the number of elements it has (especially in the case of yours where there's no data shuffling involved). Hence, the `DataFrame` materialized when `count` is called will not load any data and will not pass into your exception throwing. You can easily do the experiment by defining your own `DefaultSource` and `Relation` and see that calling `count` on a `DataFrame` will always end up  in the method `buildScan` with no `requiredColumns` no matter how many columns you did select (cf. `org.apache.spark.sql.sources.interfaces` to understand more). It's actually a very efficient optimization ;-)

In `RDD`s though, there's no such optimizations (that's why one should always try to use `DataFrame`s when possible). Hence the `count` on `RDD` executes all the lineage and returns the sum of all sizes of the iterators composing any partitions.

Calling `dataframe.count` goes into the first explanation, but calling `dataframe.rdd.count` goes into the second as you did build an `RDD` out of your `DataFrame`. Note that calling `dataframe.cache().count` forces the `dataframe` to be materialized as you required Spark to cache the results (hence it needs to load all the data and transform it). But it does have the side-effect of caching your data...

Comment: Isn't `cache` a suggestion to spark rather than forcing it to materialize?

Answer (score 4):

It appears that `df.cache.count` is the way to go:

```
scala> val myUDF = udf((i:Int) => {if(i==1000) throw new RuntimeException;i})
myUDF: org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedFunction = UserDefinedFunction(<function1>,IntegerType,Some(List(IntegerType)))

scala> val df = sc.parallelize(1 to 1000).toDF("id")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: int]

scala> df.withColumn("test",myUDF($"id")).show(10)
[rdd_51_0]
+---+----+
| id|test|
+---+----+
|  1|   1|
|  2|   2|
|  3|   3|
|  4|   4|
|  5|   5|
|  6|   6|
|  7|   7|
|  8|   8|
|  9|   9|
| 10|  10|
+---+----+
only showing top 10 rows

scala> df.withColumn("test",myUDF($"id")).count
res13: Long = 1000

scala> df.withColumn("test",myUDF($"id")).cache.count
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function($anonfun$1: (int) => int)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown Source)
.
.
.
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException
```

[Source](http://apache-spark-developers-list.1001551.n3.nabble.com/Will-count-always-trigger-an-evaluation-of-each-row-tp21018p21019.html)

Comment: although this seems to work, it has a side-effect (i.e. the caching)

Comment: spark does not always have to execute everything you may intend it to in order to perform count, this will sometimes work

Answer (score 3):

I prefer to use `df.save.parquet()`. This does add disc I/o time that you can estimate and subtract out later, but you are positive that spark performed each step you expected and did not trick you with lazy evaluation.

Comment: How can I estimate the disc I/o time Dan?

Also, will collect function work? Or will it also add some overhead time?

Comment: I assume you have a "df" and you are doing "X" actions it.
To get the baseline time, just do df.save.parquet(), and time that. Then do you methods on df, and do df_prime.save.parquet().

The first one will let you know how long it takes to simply save the df.