# How to cache resulting dataframe from sql query

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I've seen few questions on SO about caching sql tables but none of them seems to be exactly answering my question.

The resulting dataframe from a query (from sqlContext.sql("...")) does not seems to be cachable like a regular dataframe.

Here is some example code (spark 2.2):

```
import org.apache.spark.sql._

def isCached(df: DataFrame) = spark.sharedState.cacheManager.lookupCachedData(df.queryExecution.logical).isDefined

val df = List("1", "2", "3").toDF.cache
df.show
isCached(df) // 1) Here, isCached returns 'true'

df.createOrReplaceTempView("myTable")
spark.catalog.isCached("myTable")

val df2 = spark.sqlContext.sql("select value, count(*) from myTable group by value").cache
df2.show
isCached(df2) // 2) (???) returns 'false'

val df3 = spark.sqlContext.sql("select value, 'a', count(*) from myTable group by value")
df3.registerTempTable("x")
spark.sqlContext.cacheTable("x")
df3.show
spark.catalog.isCached("x") // Returns 'true'
isCached(df3) // 3) (???) Returns 'false'

spark.sqlContext.uncacheTable("myTable")
spark.catalog.isCached("myTable") // OK: Returns 'false'
isCached(df) // OK: Returns 'false'
spark.catalog.isCached("x") // 4) (???) Returns 'false'
```

Spark UI shows some storage associated to df2 but it seems to be tied to df.  Usually, we do `.cache()` followed by `.count()` to materialize and then `unpersist` parent dataframe when not needed anymore.  In this example, when unpersisting `df`, storage seen in spark UI for `df2` and `df3` disappear as well.

So how do we get (2), (3) or most importantly (4) to return true ?

Comment: Btw: `count` does NOT materialize the dataframe, you nedd `df.rdd.count`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42714291/how-to-force-dataframe-evaluation-in-spark

Comment: That is indeed very misleading!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while, I think it may be useful to post an answer to my question.

The trick is to truncate relation lineage with a new dataframe.

For that, I call `spark.createDataFrame(df.rdd, df.schema).cache()`.
Others have suggested to call `rdd.cache.count` but that seems to be a lot more inefficient than creating a new one without materializing the underlying rdd.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql._

def isCached(df: DataFrame) = spark.sharedState.cacheManager.lookupCachedData(df.queryExecution.logical).isDefined

val df = List("1", "2", "3").toDF.cache
df.count // cache the df.
isCached(df) // 1) Here, isCached returns 'true'

df.createOrReplaceTempView("myTable")
spark.catalog.isCached("myTable")

val df2Temp = spark.sqlContext.sql("select value, count(*) from myTable group by value")
// truncate lineage and materialize new dataframe
val df2Cached = spark.createDataFrame(df2Temp.rdd, df2Temp.schema).cache
df2Cached.count
isCached(df2Cached) // 2) returns 'true'
df2Cached.createOrReplaceTempView("x")

// Still cached
isCached(df) 
spark.catalog.isCached("myTable")

// parent df not needed anymore
spark.sqlContext.uncacheTable("myTable")
spark.catalog.isCached("myTable") // OK: Returns 'false'
isCached(df) // OK: Returns 'false'

spark.catalog.isCached("x") // Still cached
```

Comment: Note: Starting with spark 2.4, it is now possible to unpersist parent dataframe without affecting cached child dataframes!