# Would a forced Spark DataFrame materialization work as a checkpoint?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a large and complex DataFrame with nested structures in Spark 2.1.0 (pySpark) and I want to add an ID column to it. The way I did it was to add a column like this:

```
df= df.selectExpr('*','row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY File ORDER BY NULL) AS ID')
```

So it goes e.g. from this:

```
File     A        B
a.txt    valA1    [valB11,valB12]
a.txt    valA2    [valB21,valB22]
```

to this:

```
File     A        B                  ID
a.txt    valA1    [valB11,valB12]    1
a.txt    valA2    [valB21,valB22]    2
```

After I add this column, I don't immediately trigger a materialization in Spark, but I first branch the DataFrame to a new variable:

```
dfOutput = df.select('A','ID')
```

with only columns A and ID and I write `dfOutput` to Hive, so I get e.g. **Table1**:

```
A        ID
valA1    1
valA2    2
```

So far so good. Then I continue using `df` for further transformations, namely I explode some of the nested arrays in the columns and drop the original, like this:

```
df = df.withColumn('Bexpl',explode('B')).drop('B')
```

and I get this:

```
File     A        Bexpl      ID
a.txt    valA1    valB11     1
a.txt    valA1    valB12     1
a.txt    valA2    valB21     2
a.txt    valA2    valB22     2
```

and output other tables from it, sometimes after creating a second ID column since there are more rows from the exploded arrays. E.g. I create **Table2**:

```
df= df.selectExpr('*','row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY File ORDER BY NULL) AS ID2')
```

to get:

```
File     A        Bexpl      ID    ID2
a.txt    valA1    valB11     1     1
a.txt    valA1    valB12     1     2
a.txt    valA2    valB21     2     3
a.txt    valA2    valB22     2     4
```

and output as earlier:

```
dfOutput2 = df.select('Bexpl','ID','ID2')
```

to get:

```
Bexpl      ID    ID2
valB11     1     1
valB12     1     2
valB21     2     3
valB22     2     4
```

I would expect that the values of the first ID column remain the same and match the data for each row from the point that this column was created. This would allow me to keep a relation between **Table1** created from `dfOutput` and subsequent tables from `df`, like `dfOutput2` and the resulting **Table2**.

The problem is that ID and ID2 are not as they should be in the example above, but mixed up, and I'm trying to find out why. My guess is that the values of the first ID column are not deterministic because `df` is not materialized before branching to `dfOutput`. So when the data is actually materialized when saving the table from `dfOutput`, the rows are shuffled and IDs are different from the data that is materialized on a later point from `df`, as in `dfOutput2`. I am however not sure, so my questions are:

1. Is my assumption correct, that IDs are generated differently for the different branches although I add the ID column before branching?
2. Would materializing the DataFrame before branching to `dfOutput`, e.g. through `df.cache().count()`, ensure a fixed ID column which I can later branch however I want from `df`, so that I can use this as a checkpoint?
3. If not, how can I solve this?

I would appreciate any help or at least quick confirmation because I can't test it properly. Spark would shuffle the data only if it doesn't have enough memory, and reaching that point would mean loading a lot of data and in turn need a long time, and may still provide coincidentally good results (already tried with smaller datasets).

Comment: Without fully reading your question: `df.cache().count()` does not materialize the dataframe (but `df.rdd.cache().count()`). Still it is not the same as e.g. checkpoiting because the lineage is not truncated

Comment: Thanks. the `cache().count()` I saw here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42714291/how-to-force-dataframe-materialization-n-spark but what do you mean not truncated? What I want to achieve is prepare a DF with an ID column through `row_number()` then branch to two tables by still having the same ID values, because apparently if I branch these, the ID columns is created dinamically and thus differently for each output. How can I prepare a base DF with an ID column already generated, and then transform it further?

Answer (score 0):

I don't full understand the problem but the address some points:

- With window definition as:

  ```
  (PARTITION BY ... ORDER BY NULL)
  ```

  order of values in the window is effectively random. There is no reason for it to stable.
- > Spark would shuffle the data only if it doesn't have enough memory,

  Spark will shuffle every time it is required by the execution plan (grouping, window functions). You confused this with disk spills, which don't induce randomness.
- > Would materializing the DataFrame before branching to dfOutput, e.g. through df.cache().count()

  No. You cannot depend on caching for correctness.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't group or use any other window functions except for row_number(). The point is, how do I create an ID row, explode a column, and create a second ID, but also maintain the first ID? If materializing doesn't help, there should be another way, right?