# Spark dataframe is being re-evaluated after a cache

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am running into some issues using cache on a spark dataframe. My expectation is that after a cache on a dataframe, the dataframe is created and cached the fist time it is needed. Any further calls to the dataframe should be from the cache

here's my code:

```
val mydf = spark.sql("read about 400 columns from a hive table").
  withColumn ("newcol", someudf("existingcol")).
  cache()
```

To test I ran a mydf.count() twice. I would expect the first time to take some time since the data is being cached. But the second time should be instantaneous?

What I am actually seeing is that it takes the same time for both the counts. This first one comes back pretty quickly which I think tells me that the data was not cached. If I remove the withColumn part of the code and just cache the raw data, the second count is instantaneous

Am I doing something wrong? How can I load raw data from hive, add columns and then cache the dataframe for further use? Using spark 2.3

Any help will be great!

Comment: Could you check explainPlan() for both and the Spark UIs storage tab to see if the data is actually persisted?

Answer (score 0):

As you are caching a dataset/dataframe, se the [documented default behavior](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset@cache():Dataset.this.type):

> `def cache(): Dataset.this.type`
>
> Persist this Dataset with the default storage level (`MEMORY_AND_DISK`).

So for your case you can try [`persist(MEMORY_ONLY)`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset@persist(newLevel:org.apache.spark.storage.StorageLevel):Dataset.this.type)

> `def persist(newLevel: StorageLevel): Dataset.this.type`
>
> Persist this Dataset with the given storage level.
>
> `newLevel` One of: `MEMORY_ONLY`, `MEMORY_AND_DISK`, `MEMORY_ONLY_SER`, `MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER`, `DISK_ONLY`, `MEMORY_ONLY_2`, `MEMORY_AND_DISK_2`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

the problem with your case is that `mydf.count()` is not actually materializing the dataframe (i.e. not all columns are read, your udf will no be called). That is because `count()` is highly optimized.

To make sure the entire dataframe is cached into memory, you should repeat your experiment with `mydf.rdd.count()` or another query (e.g. using sorting and/or aggregation)

See e.g. [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42714291/how-to-force-dataframe-evaluation-in-spark)

Comment: That does not make a difference. I tried running an agg too, the response time for multiple queries remains the same. The only way i can get it to work fast is by removing the withColumn, but I need it

Answer (score 0):

If its relevant

`.cache/persist` is lazy evaluation, to force it you can use the spark SQL's API which have the capability change form lazy to eager.

```
CACHE [ LAZY ] TABLE table_identifier
    [ OPTIONS ( 'storageLevel' [ = ] value ) ] [ [ AS ] query ]
```

Unless LAZY specified it would be eager mode, you need to register a temp table prior to this.

Pseudo code would be:

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView("dummyTbl")
spark.sql("cache table dummyTbl")
```

More on the document reference - https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-syntax-aux-cache-cache-table.html