# Why method count( ) does not get true num of rows?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset

I was running my program on a cluster and I encountered a strange problem. When I try to count the number of rows in a particular dataset `ds`, I find that `count()` does not return the correct value. When I add `ds.persist()` before `ds.count()`, count result is correct. Why is that? Doesn't `count()` itself have operations such as *cache* or *persist*? Why are rows loss?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is do with the lazy evaluation.  I remember an old thread on spark developer community that due to the optimisations on dataframe and dataset APIs, a count may not necessarily trigger the enitre dataframe/dataset evaluation. Hence the count may not be accurate.

However, if you do a df.rdd.count or ds.rdd.count or do a a cache or persist first on the dataset/dataframe and then do a count, it will evaluate the entire dataframe or dataset and the count will be accurate.

Looking at another thread [How to force DataFrame evaluation in Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42714291/how-to-force-dataframe-evaluation-in-spark) please see the reply be Vince.Bdn which is in-line with my chain of thoughts.

If you want to further validate it, create a large dataframe and do the count before a persist and another one after the persist and look at the DAG, that should validate the same. in my case I went with a dataframe of 1 million records with 6 columns.