# Why Spark DataFrame is creating wrong number of partitions?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, parquet

I have a spark dataframe with 2 columns - `col1` and `col2`.

```
scala> val df = List((1, "a")).toDF("col1", "col2")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [col1: int, col2: string]
```

When I write `df` on disk in `parquet` format, to write all the data in number of files equal to the number of unique values in `col1` I do a `repartition` using `col1`, like this:

```
scala> df.repartition(col("col1")).write.partitionBy("col1").parquet("file")
```

Above code produces only one file in filesystem. But, the number of shuffle operations becomes 200.

[image]

I am not able to understand one thing here that if `col1` contains only one value, i.e., `1` then why it is creating 200 partitions in `repartition` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`repartition(columnName)` per default creates 200 partitions (more specific, `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions` partitions), no matter how many unique values of `col1` there are. If there is only 1 unique value of `col1`, then 199 of the partitions are empty. On the other hand, if you have more than 200 unique values of `col1`, you will will have multiple values of `col1` per partition.

If you only want 1 partition, then you can do `repartition(1,col("col1"))` or just `coalesce(1)`. But not that `coalesce` does not behave the same in the sense that `coalesce` me be moved further up in your code suscht that you may loose parallelism (see [How to prevent Spark optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44494656/how-to-prevent-spark-optimization))

If you want to check the content of your partition, I've made 2 methods for this:

```
// calculates record count per partition
def inspectPartitions(df: DataFrame) = {
    import df.sqlContext.implicits._
    df.rdd.mapPartitions(partIt => {
       Iterator(partIt.toSeq.size)
    }
    ).toDF("record_count")
}

// inspects how a given key is distributed accross the partition of a dataframe
def inspectPartitions(df: DataFrame, key: String) = {
    import df.sqlContext.implicits._
    df.rdd.mapPartitions(partIt => {
      val part = partIt.toSet
      val partSize = part.size
        val partKeys = part.map(r => r.getAs[Any](key).toString.trim)
        val partKeyStr = partKeys.mkString(", ")
        val partKeyCount = partKeys.size
       Iterator((partKeys.toArray,partSize))
    }
    ).toDF("partitions","record_count")
}
```

Now you can e.g. check your dataframe like this:

```
inspectPartitions(df.repartition(col("col1"),"col1")
.where($"record_count">0)
.show
```

Answer (score 2):

In the Spark SQL shuffle world， the default number of shuffle partition is 200, which is controlled by `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions`