# Difference between repartition(1) and coalesce(1)

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

In our project, we are using `repartition(1)` to write data into table, I am interested to know why `coalesce(1)` cannot be used here because `repartition` is a costly operation compared to `coalesce`.

I know `repartition` distributes data evenly across partitions, but when the output file is of single part file, why can't we use `coalesce(1)`?

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44494656/coalesce-reduces-parallelism-of-entire-stage-spark

Comment: Differences between `coalesce(1)` and `repartition(1)` may be experienced as a result of older Spark version: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71154277

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You state nothing else in terms of logic.

- `coalesce` will use existing partitions to minimize shuffling. In case of coalsece(1) and counterpart may be not a big deal, but one can take this guiding principle that `repartition` creates new partitions and hence does a full shuffle. That said, coalsece can be said to minimize the amount of shuffling.
- In my spare time I chanced upon this https://medium.com/airbnb-engineering/on-spark-hive-and-small-files-an-in-depth-look-at-spark-partitioning-strategies-a9a364f908 excellent article. Look for the quote: *Coalesce sounds useful in some cases, but has some problems.*

Answer (score 11):

`coalesce` has an issue where if you're calling it using a number smaller than your current number of executors, the number of executors used to process that step will be limited by the number you passed in to the coalesce function.

The `repartition` function avoids this issue by shuffling the data. In any scenario where you're reducing the data down to a single partition (or really, less than half your number of executors), you should almost always use `repartition` over coalesce because of this. The shuffle caused by repartition is a small price to pay compared to the single-threaded operation of a call to `coalesce(1)`