# repartition vs coalesce performance on smaller partition

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark

I'm reading input data from s3, writing the result data back to s3.

- Input data volume (from delta table): 5TB
- Result data volume : ~5GB

I used different options during write as below:

- Spark default behaviour (multiple files) : 6hr
- repartition(11) : completed in 6 hr
- coalesce(11) : cancelled as it was overrunning for 10+hr

I have used same cluster configuration (5 worker + 1 Driver + 16 core/64 GB mem per machine) for all of the above different runs.

Just curious as why coalesce is running long compared to repartition? Should not coalesce faster due to no shuffle involved?

Comment: Matthew, would you be able to add your code ?

Comment: I believe coalesce() doesn't guarantee the avoidance of shuffling. If the number of partitions specified in coalesce() is much smaller than the current number of partitions, or if the data is not evenly distributed across the partitions, Spark might still need to shuffle the data between nodes to meet the desired partition count.

Comment: its a lengthy workflow, essentially just adding repartition or coalesce just during final write to have N number of files for a specific need. Specifically looking for why repartition fares well compared to coalesce for smaller (10) partitions from initial >1K partitions during read?

Comment: Some time ago, I encountered a similar issue. Instead of reading all the files simultaneously, consider fetching the file metadata from the input S3. Utilize this metadata to merge multiple small files into a larger DataFrame and initiate multiple Spark jobs concurrently. Each job will then write data into one file in your `target S3`. It was used to take more than 24 hours to load > 3k files & it reduced to 1 hour with 50 parallel threads.

Comment: As @s.polam mentioned, you need to add more details. Without understanding what teh partitioning keys are, how many partitions are there and what's teh size of each partition, it's hard to answer. All questions specifically about your "final `Dataframe`" that you're repartitioning.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31612810/55209

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Coalesce reduces parallelism of entire stage (spark)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44494656/coalesce-reduces-parallelism-of-entire-stage-spark)

Comment: @Kashyap, As I mentioned I had same issue as question asked by Matthew .. & added solution how did i solved.

Comment: @mazaneicha perfect, the post answered.

Comment: @s.polam thanks for the details. Just so that I completely understand, could you please elaborate more on 'fetching metadata', 'merge multiple small files', 'initiate multiple spark jobs'?

Comment: For metadata, You can check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61317600/how-to-get-files-metadata-when-retrieving-data-from-hdfs/61423874#61423874 it is for hdfs.. I believe it should work for s3 as well. for remaining I will add it as part of answer as it may not fit in this comment.